# Ngrx effects not working when in a preloaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx, ngrx-effects, preloading

I have two modules, let's call them `EagerModule` and `PrealodedModule`. Both of them have their own feature reducers and effects.

`EagerModule` is loaded eagerly in the app, meaning its in the list of `AppModule`'s imports.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // .. other modules
        EagerModule
    ]
```

`PreloadedModule`, on the other hand, is loaded lazily, but since I am using `preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules`, we can say that it's basically preloaded (meaning, it's being loaded just after all eager modules are loaded).

I am trying to dispatch an action from `PrealoadedModule` in a `EagerModule`'s component. However, it seems like the effects are not being initialized as my action doesn't perform the http request that it is supposed to. I tried hacking this by only dispatching this action after I have a value in `PreloadedModule`'s state selector, however, this didn't work either.

The only way I can get this working is if I load `PreloadedModule` eagerly, but that is not what I want to achieve.

So, how can I make effects from a preloaded module work in another module?

Comment: How are you including the effects module?

Comment: In `AppModule` it is `EffectsModule.forRoot(effects)`, and in all feature module it goes like `EffectsModule.forFeature(effects)`

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I'm in a similar situation but the only difference is i'm not using preloading strategy.  I have a effect that listen to an action on a eagerloaded module but when that action is dispatched, the effect doesn't run

Comment: Having same issue, have you found solution to this?